# Transformar uma função python em uma função em PHP

Tags: php, python

Alguém saberia transformar essa função que está em python pra uma função em php?

```
def createSignature(clientId, apiKey, privateKey, nonce):
    message = str(nonce) + str(clientId) + apiKey 
    signature = hmac.new(privateKey, message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Bem, o código não está indentado, então suponho que seja:

```
def createSignature(clientId, apiKey, privateKey, nonce): 
 message = str(nonce) + str(clientId) + apiKey 
 signature = hmac.new(privateKey, message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

---

Isso seria exatamente:

```
function createSignature($id, $pk, $sk, $nonce){
     $message = $nonce . $id . $pk; 
     $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $message, $sk, false);
}
```

O [`hash_hmac`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.hash-hmac.php) já tem o resultado em hexadecimal, não há porque converte-lo, por isso não há qualquer equivalente do `.hexdigest()` sendo utilizado. É claro que deve adicionar algum `return` (ou algum outro método para obter as informações procesasdas), mas isso não está presente no código indicado.